# Passing parameter to next JSP page by a 3rd-party-Servlet-generated form

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, parameter-passing

I'm trying to fix a bug in a legacy application in my organization. I need to pass an extra parameter in a dynamically generated form.

`page1.jsp`

```
<%
    request.setAttribute("param", param);
    // ...
%>

<form name="xx">   
    ...
</form>   
<jsp:include page="servlet1" />
```

The `Servlet1` is calling another `Servlet2`, which in turn calls `Servlet3` to print some code to `page1.jsp`. The generated HTML output looks like this:

```
<form name="xx">   
    ...
</form>   
<form name="yy" action="page2.jsp" >   
    ...   
    <input type="submit">   
</form>
```

I need to be able to pass "param" value from `page1.jsp` to `page2.jsp`. The `request.setAttribute()` is not working. The Servlet class `Servlet3` is vendor provided, so I cannot set a hidden form variable inside form "yy" to pass it to `page2.jsp`.

How can I achieve this in other way?

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest bet is to use JavaScript to add a hidden input field to the form. Add the following script to the bottom of your JSP, *after* the point where the form is been inserted.

```
<script>
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "hidden";
    input.name = "param";
    input.value = "${param}";
    document.forms['yy'].appendChild(input);
</script>
```

You're however only dependent on whether the enduser supports JS. The only server-side alternative would be to alter the output of `Servlet3` yourself with help of `HttpServletResponseWrapper`.

Comment: unfortunately that form name "yy" is also Servlet3 generated.. it is not the same every time..

Comment: If it is always the last form of the document, use `document.forms[document.forms.length - 1]` instead. Or if it is always the 2nd form, use `document.forms[1]` instead. Or, better, go ahead with capturing the response. Then you can just do a `writer.write(servlet3ResponseAsString.replace("</form>", "<input type=\"hidden\" ... /></form>"));`

Comment: @Balusc.. what do you say about setting a session attribute in page1.jsp and retreiving it in page2.jsp.. Is that a good idea? can you validate pros and cons?

Comment: It will fail when the user opens the same page in multiple windows in the same session and submits it in different order.

Comment: @BalusC.. your JS suggestion worked like a charm.. thanku very much bro